# How do I dynamically change the gallery source in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

Below is the sample data:
[image]

Below is the vertical gallery where it displays the areaName based on storey column:
[image]

Below is the image for areaDescription content in a vertical gallery as well:
[image]

The desire outcome I would like to have is:
For instance, if I select "office" item in the vertical gallery, it should navigate me to a screen showing the areaDescription for the office. Let's say if I go back and select "Meeting room" item in the vertical gallery, it should navigate me to the SAME screen showing the areaDescription for the meeting room. In short, I want to on item select in vertical gallery to navigate me to the same screen and change the content (checklists) of the screen dynamically.

It would be good to possibly provide sample canvas-app functions so I could understand. I really have no idea how it should do it :( Please help by seeing this above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this for Gallery2 Items property:

```
Filter('Data Source Name Here', areaName = Gallery1.Selected.areaName)
```

And then set the Items property for the label in your second gallery to be

```
ThisItem.areaDescription
```